# How do I change texture of potions in resource pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a resource pack. I would simply stick to the default texture for potions, but my resource pack is supposed to have 100% solid colors, and the potion varies in tones from one part to another. How do I fix this? I heard that modifying items.png would work. Could you show me where in the photo should I put the texture?

(Sorry, don't know how to pass images from my computer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minecraft doesn't use `items.png` anymore, since it has switched to using individual files for each item and block. (If you're using tiled PNG images in your resourcepack, you should be aware that these are no longer the correct format.)

There are four textures for potions:

- `potion_bottle_drinkable.png`
- `potion_bottle_empty.png`
- `potion_bottle_splash.png`
- `potion_overlay.png`

You can see these files by opening the Minecraft jarfile (in `.minecraft\versions\1.6.4\1.6.4.jar`) using a utility like **7zip** and navigating down into the `assets\minecraft\textures\items\` folder inside the jar.

Your resource pack should have the same folder structure, as well as a `pack.png` file and a `pack.mcmeta` file at the top level.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I won't be able to upload when finished!

Comment: You're welcome! That's okay; I'm sure I'll see it on the forums.

Answer (score -3):

You need to create a resource pack ([Shown in my youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1Yeg8bk7bYR0P-JF1TudNA)) then, create a potions  folder and find a picture of a cool potion bottle on line that you want to use. After that, just save the picture, copy it, paste it 4 times, and name them:

- potion_bottle_drinkable.png,
- potion_bottle_empty.png,
- potion_bottle_splash.png,
- potion_overlay.png

Hope this helps!

Comment: This either contains a typo in the URL or it's spam. Uncharacteristically, I can't tell which.

Comment: It was a typo. However, this just links to your channel (as you did mention), but it would be more worthwhile to link the video that outlines this directly.

Comment: @Ben What I was getting at is that there's nothing in *that* channel except a video about Justin Bieber, which makes me think the link is completely wrong.